# Getting the connection string during installation with InstallShield Professional

Tags: xml, connection-string, installshield

I'm building an installer using InstallShield Professional edition. In my XML File Changes View, I already added the file, and the node to receive the value from the user:

[image: XML File Changes View]

But I don't know how to get the value itself from the user. I checked the help article, but it says:

> The following procedure demonstrates how to use the name of the SQL Server that an end user selects in the SQL Login dialog as the content for one of the elements in your XML file.

However, I don't have any SQL Login dialog from the list of available dialogs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a New SQL Connection to my project, and then the SQLLogin dialog appeared and was available for use.
Go to SQL Scripts and right click on SQL Scripts and choose New SQL Connection and go from there.